# Anchor is Being Modified by Current Page URL

Tags: php, url

In my site I am in the following page:

> mysite.com/especialidad/ensenanza/formacion-profesional/?region=alava

The relevant part of the PHP template that contains that page is:

```
<?php
    /* Get the Queried Object */
    $term = get_queried_object();

    $enlace_especialidad = get_term_link( $term );

    /* Get the Queried Object */
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query(
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'especialidad_preparador',
            'meta_value' => $term->term_id,
            'number' => 100,

            'meta_query' => $meta_query,
        )
    );
?>
<?php echo $enlace_especialidad; ?>
<h1 class="titulo_taxonomia">Preparadores de Oposiciones a <a href="<?php $enlace_especialidad ?>"><?php echo $term->name ?></a>
<?php 
    if ($_GET['region']) {
        $taxonomia_region = get_term_by('slug', $_GET['region'], 'region');

        echo 'en <a href="'. get_term_link( $taxonomia_region ) .'">'. $taxonomia_region->name .'</a>';
    }
?>
```

When I echo the var $enlace_especialidad (just to check its value) the result is:

> mysite.com/especialidad/ensenanza/formacion-profesional/

Instead, the part that refers to the URL: Preparadores de Oposiciones a ***`<a href="<?php $enlace_especialidad ?>"><?php echo $term->name ?></a>`*** links to:

> mysite.com/especialidad/ensenanza/formacion-profesional/***?region=alava***

The problem is that ?region=alava isn't in the var $enlace_especialidad, and I don't know how it appears when used in an anchor. On the other hand it is the current page URL, and I guess there must be a relation.

Comment: `$taxonomia_region->name` added to your anchor tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LAST EDIT**

You forgot to **echo** before the link, so the anchor is void. That's why you see incoherence with the printed output before.

---

`?region=alava` is here because it is a result of a `$_GET` request with region as parameter. So it is in addition of your URL part.

So your URL is just fine, the additionnal part is treated in this followed part :

```
<?php 
    if ($_GET['region']) {
        $taxonomia_region = get_term_by('slug', $_GET['region'], 'region');

        echo 'en <a href="'. get_term_link( $taxonomia_region ) .'">'. $taxonomia_region->name .'</a>';
    }
?>
```

The part with `get_term_link( $taxonomia_region )` contains the `$_GET['region']` result part if it exist.

**See documentation of $_GET** : 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

**EDIT**

After our discussion in the comment, there's a difference with this method when you use different kind of parameter, ie `get_term_link( $term );` or `get_term_link( $taxonomia_region );`

> Since the term can be an object, integer, or string, make sure that
>   any numbers you pass in are explicitly converted to an integer
>   (example: (int) $term_id). Otherwise the function will assume that
>   $term is a slug instead of a term ID.

That's why you get `mysite.com/especialidad/ensenanza/formacion-profesional/` with `get_term_link( $taxonomia_region );` because you pass a slug as parameter.

And you get `mysite.com/especialidad/ensenanza/formacion-profesional/?region=alava` with `get_term_link( $term );` because you pass an object as parameter.

**Source** : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/

Comment: Hello Vincent G, I don't understand. The following code `<?php 
    if ($_GET['region']) {
        $taxonomia_region = get_term_by('slug', $_GET['region'], 'region');

        echo 'en <a href="'. get_term_link( $taxonomia_region ) .'">'. $taxonomia_region->name .'</a>';
    }
?>` outputs an anchor with the following URL: mysite.com/region/alava/. So, the first part of the code I guess that should output mysite.com/especialidad/ensenanza/formacion-profesional/ and nothing else.

Comment: I think it's because of the `get_queried_object()` function. Try to use the function `get_permalink()` to retrieve the URL instead : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

You said you were on this page `mysite.com/especialidad/ensenanza/formacion-profesional/?region=alava` so you get the same URL when you hover the link right ? Try to remove the parameter in the URL and hover the link again.

Comment: I don't see the relation, get_term_link( $taxonomia_region) equals to mysite.com/region/alava/, but when used in an anchor isn't modified. While get_term_link( $term) which equals to mysite.com/especialidad/ensenanza/formacion-profesional/ is being modified.

Comment: Hello @Vicent G, thanks for your help, but I don't understand int or I'm missing something. If I use `<?php $enlace_especialidad = get_term_link( $term ); echo $enlace_especialidad;` I got the link without ?region=alava. If I use it in the anchor it is rewrited. And in my code using $term or $taxonomia_region is exactly the same, both are objects. I think that ?region=alava is being added after, but I don't know how and when exactly.

Comment: It's hard to debug without seing the live URL then, can you provide it please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110276/discussion-between-kevin-and-vincent-g).